# PFQueryTableViewController bringing duplicate results - Pagination

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pagination, parse-platform

I am using `PFQueryTableViewController` to retrieve some objects from my Parse database. I am using pagination to improve the performance of my app. However, when I ask to load more objects the `queryForTable` gets executed again and bring the same results again.

Do you guys know whether this is a bug or there is something I can do.

Here is my code:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    NSLog(@"To aqui %@",self.location.name);
    PFQuery *imageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WallImageObject"];
    [imageQuery whereKey:@"geoPoint" nearGeoPoint:self.location.coordinatesInGeoPoint withinKilometers:0.5];
    [imageQuery whereKey:@"venueName" equalTo:self.location.name];
    [imageQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

     // If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
     if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
         imageQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
     }

     // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
     // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
     if (self.objects.count == 0) {
         imageQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
     }

     return imageQuery;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    FeedPhotoCell *cell = (FeedPhotoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSString *facebbokUserID = object[@"UserId"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=100&height=100",facebbokUserID];
    NSURL *facebookProfilePicURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [cell.profilePhoto setImageWithURL:facebookProfilePicURL];
    cell.profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    cell.profilePhoto.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235.0/255.0 green:80.0/255.0 blue:80.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    cell.profilePhoto.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIImageView *photoView = (UIImageView *)cell.photoPost;
    PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
        photoView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }];

    return cell;
 }
```

PS: I have done some further tests and discovered that this issue only happens when I try `[imageQuery whereKey:@"geoPoint" nearGeoPoint:self.location.coordinatesInGeoPoint withinKilometers:0.5];`

Regards

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could imagine that happening is that when you invoke
imageQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
The query is being filled with results from the cache and then when you load the next page its being filled with results from the network which are duplicated a second time

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you probably have figured this out by now but you do realize that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method you chose (at least for your code on here) is for a UITableView and not a PFQueryTableViewController. I believe this is needed for all parse related functionality like this and pull to refresh.